# How many executors required to process the 80 GB file?

Tags: apache-spark

Available Hardware Config - 
16 GB with 8 Cores

What will be my number of executors and executor memory required to process the data ?

Data format -  data is delimited text format with 20 columns , aggregation like average needs to be performed on one of the column .

Answer (score 1):

More executors only makes a job or stage complete faster.

Your work will be broken up into tasks, and each of those tasks will be run by an executor. If there are more tasks than executors, they simply queue. If you have only one executor then the queue is longer! This should determine the ability to complete.

A better question would be 'how much memory should I give to an executor'.

Comment: How much memory can be given to executor based on input size ? I find many explanations without considering inputsize.

Comment: @prady how many partitions? You need at least enough memory to hold a single partition at a time. If you have 16GB on your hardware or VM then Spark will allocate just under 10GB to the executor ([memory management](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview)). In that case you will want at least 10 partitions, and possibly more, to ensure they are smaller than 10GB each.